# 100% cpu usage in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm use views , cck ,panel and several modules use in my site 
and now when open front-page delay for request from drupal site and Apache for loaded page is 20 seconds and now when disable views modules my website is no delay and fast loaded and no usage 100 CPU

next question
how to moderate for /admin/builds/blocks because i have 150 blocks and this loaded page is very slow , can i this page show in several page? or show any region blocks display in page?

Comment: Try to ask one question per question, please.

Answer (score 0):

Views 3 supports query cache and output cache, which help you save your resource.

Answer (score 0):

Views can be a resource-hog if you have complex or large queries. Try installing the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and turn on query logging. Then when you go to your front page, you will see a list of all database queries made to render that page at the very bottom. Any troublesome queries will be highlighted in red.

As nice as views and panels are, sometimes you need to code by hand to get better performance. Those modules bring a lot of "weight" to a page.